# Which items to include in accuracy_score() to find accuracy in classification problems

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, evaluation

I have this training and testing data to predict the values of Item_outlet_sales for the testing data .This is the train_data_df and test _data_df.

Train_data_df

```
                  Item_Weight  Item_Visibility  Item_MRP  Item_Outlet_Sales
 Item_Identifier                                                           
   FDA15                   9.30         0.016047  249.8092          3735.1380
   DRC01                   5.92         0.019278   48.2692           443.4228
   FDN15                  17.50         0.016760  141.6180          2097.2700
   FDX07                  19.20         0.000000  182.0950           732.3800
   NCD19                   8.93         0.000000   53.8614           994.7052
```

Tesst_data_df

```
                  Item_Weight  Item_Visibility  Item_MRP
Item_Identifier                                        
 FDW58                 20.750         0.007565  107.8622
 FDW14                  8.300         0.038428   87.3198
 NCN55                 14.600         0.099575  241.7538
 FDQ58                  7.315         0.015388  155.0340
 FDY38                   -999        0.118599  234.2300
```

I have included the numerical columns only and dropped the unnecessary ones .

The code predicts the values for testing data but i'm confused as to how i should predict the accuracy,precision,recall,f1 scores of these predicted values .

```
import pandas as pd 
import sklearn 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from sklearn import preprocessing,cross_validation, svm,neighbors
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix,mean_squared_error

train_data_df= train_data_df.drop(['Item_Type','Outlet_Identifier','Item_Fat_Content','Outlet_Size','Outlet_Establishment_Year','Outlet_Location_Type','Outlet_Type','Item_Type'],axis=1)

test_data_df= test_data_df.drop(['Item_Type','Outlet_Identifier','Item_Fat_Content','Outlet_Size','Outlet_Location_Type','Outlet_Establishment_Year','Outlet_Type','Item_Type'],axis=1)

train_data_df.fillna(-999,inplace=True)

test_data_df.fillna(-999,inplace=True)

X = np.array(train_data_df.drop(['Item_Outlet_Sales'], axis=1 ),dtype=np.int64)

y= np.array(train_data_df['Item_Outlet_Sales'],dtype=np.int64)

test_data_df = np.array(test_data_df)

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test_0= cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.6665)

clf =neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier() 

clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

test_data_predict = clf.predict(test_data_df)

print test_data_predict
```

Now what shall i put in accuracy_score() and other scores to calculate . I guess one is test_data_predict. And do i need to include cross_validation as i have used to improve the predictions.

Comment: Where are the `Item_Outlet_Sales` for the `test_data_df`?

Answer (score 0):

The classification metrics you have specified take **actual values of target** and **values predicted from the model** as input to calculate the specific metrics. You can get more information about sklearn metrics on [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-metrics).

For example, the [documentation of accuracy_score()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) specifies that you should supply `y_true` and `y_pred`.

In your case, `y_pred` should be `test_data_predict`, and `y_true` should be the values of column `Item_Outlet_Sales` from your `test_data_df`. But you have not specified them in your question.

Also, as for these four lines in your question:-

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test_0=cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y,
                                                      test_size=0.6665)
clf =neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier() 
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
X_test_predict =clf.predict(X_test)
```

`X_test_predict` can also be used to find out accuracy, but this is simply used for cross validation, to see if your estimator is not overfitting to training data.

```
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test_0, X_test_predict)
```

Comment: Yeah , i added X_test predict by mistake . The values from the dataset came as it is i.e. the testing data didn't have the Item_Outlet_Sales column. The values of the testing data are 5681 values out of 8524 values . So the Item_outlet_sales values for testing data are there but they are in the training data . So i guess i have to compare those Item_Outlet_Sales values ' from training data for corresponding values of testing data , to the test_data_predict . I mean this is what i think, do correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: I didnot understand - "The values of the testing data are 5681 values out of 8524 values. So the Item_outlet_sales values for testing data are there but they are in the training data". How can test values be in training